# how to make my game run on different devices with various resolutions?

Tags: andengine

I'm developing a game for 480*800 resolution screen,but now I want to run it on all other screens I tried to run on 7" screen but my background image and even sprite position are out of order.Can anyone please suggest me with some examples about how to make my game compatible with different screen resolutions.

I used the below code but that was of no use.I have seen somewhere that by using `FillResolutionPolicy()` along with the below code `andengine` sets automatically for different screens but I did not notice any change ,so please help me in solving it.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics)
CAMERA_WIDTH = metrics.widthPixels()
CAMERA_HEIGHT = metrics.heightPixels()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FillResolutionPolicy automatically scales everything depending on your screensize.

```
Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, 480, 880);
EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.camera);
```

This is what I use, and if I start the game on a bigger device, everything is scaled automatically.
FillResolutionPolicy is probably exactly what you need.

(The code above might not be 100% accurate as I can´t access my actual code right now)

Comment: I tried the above code it works fine for smaller devices but for bigger devices I'm getting force close can you please guide me to resolve it.

Comment: I will add my full code later today, I can´t access it right now - meanwhile, try to find where it crashes, so we can help you better (breakpoints/logcat)

Answer (score 0):

`FillResolutionPolicy()` is just for the black stripe you have either left/right or top/bottom depending on the screens aspect-ratio. see [this post](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/resolutions-t6036.html) in the andengine forum to read about resolution policy.

the camera width/height has nothing to do with the devices real resolution, since it's projected to either the devices height or the devices width (depending on the aspect ratio of your camera settings & the aspect ratio of the device). there is only one point where the DisplayMetrics are useful - get the screens density/max resolution to load res-depending sprites (like: like higher density, load larger sprites) but that's not your problem atm.

the games i tested andengine with, are all resolution independent and can be run on 4, 7 or 10 inch displays with different resolutions without any addition/code changes.

i think it's more like a coding mistake where you added sprites and background image to the scene. for example, by recalculating `CAMERA_WIDTH/_HEIGHT` with metrics and sprite positions that depend on the `CAMERA_WIDTH/_HEIGHT`, you mix up the sprite positions with the devices resolution and everything looks a bit out of order. perhaps you add some code, and i can edit my answer pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: R Hey thanks for your reply actually I have designed my game for 480*800 resolution and in my code I have specified camera_width=480 and camera_height=800 and I have set FillResolutionPolicy() now it is working fine for all devices which has resolution less than 480*800 and for devices greater than that it shows force close.